# Duplicate rows in COUNT(CASE WHEN) SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, duplicates, rows, multiple-columns

beginner SQL user here.

I need my table to look like this:

```
ModuleID | Draft | Proposed | Committed | Total
---------------------------------------------
A        |    1  |    0     |     1     | 2
```

It currently looks like this:

```
ModuleID | Draft | Proposed | Committed | Total
---------------------------------------------
A        |    1  |    0     |     1     | 1
A        |    0  |    0     |     1     | 1
```

Here is the code:

```
SELECT T3.NAME AS ModuleID, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN T4.LITERAL_NAME = 'Draft' THEN 1 END) AS Draft,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN T4.LITERAL_NAME = 'Proposed' THEN 1 END) AS Proposed,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN T4.LITERAL_NAME = 'Committed' THEN 1 END) AS Committed,
   SUM(1) AS Total

FROM ...
WHERE ...

GROUP BY T4.LITERAL_NAME,T3.NAME
```

So it's pulling the right information, but it's duplicating the Module IDs per column. I've scoured the boards and google and can't figure out what's wrong. Please help!

Comment: put the literalname and name fields in your select field list, and you'll probably find that it's NOT "duplicating" your rows. youve got unique rows and just aren't showing the fields that make them unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GROUP BY T4.LITERAL_NAME,T3.NAME
```

change to

```
GROUP BY T3.NAME
```